# Error 1053 Windows service

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have created a windows service, however when I start the service I get a 1053 error.I have installed .net framework 4 on my machine.can anybody help!!

Comment: That error code means: "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." In other words, something went wrong during startup. What that was is anyone's guess. Add some logging to your service startup code.

Comment: Show your code, in particular the calls to SetServiceStatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you are doing to much in the OnStart(). Try something like this.

'Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        ' in motion so your service can do its work.

```
    Try
        Dim worker = New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
        worker.Name = "MyWork"
        worker.IsBackground = False
        worker.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'write to a log somewhere, however you usually handle your errors

    End Try

End Sub'
```

Try something like that but we really do need more information to help you

Comment: thanks to all My problem is solved.to solve this i had re-install MS Visual C++.might be some of its components corrupted and causing the problem for service to start.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to debug further.  As others have already pointed out, "error 1053" is too generic to help much.

1) Read this link.  It tells you how to debug a service in Visual Studio.  You'll need to create a dummy "OnStart()" method (so that you can debug the "real" OnStart):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

2) Here's a good article on Windows Event logging:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39218/How-To-Create-a-Windows-Event-Log-and-Write-your-C

For starters (if you don't already have your own event log), I'd consider just appending "printf's" to a text file

3) Once you've isolated the problem to a specific part of your code, feel free to post it here.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks to all My problem is solved.to solve this i had re-install MS Visual C++.might be some of its components corrupted and causing the problem for service to start.Thanks again.